# How can I use jQuery to update a field on my rails model?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a model, Player, that has a field total_points.

On my home page, I have the players name and total_points:

```
<div id="player1">
  <h3><%= "#{@player1.first_name} #{@player1.last_name} (#{@player1.total_points})" %></h3>
</div>
```

I would like to have the total_points field on @player1 increase by 1 every time the player's name is clicked by the user. My jQuery (coffeescript) so far is:

```
/home.js.coffee
jQuery ->
  pointForPlayer1 = (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('player 1 clicked')

  $('#player1').click pointForPlayer1
```

This works (as in, it logs the message to the console), but I'm not sure how to have the click increase @player1.total_points by 1 and then re-render the message above (preferably without reloading the whole page). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a better time if you adjust your HTML so that you can find the total points easily. Something like this:

```
<div id="player1">
  <h3>
    <%= "#{@player1.first_name} #{@player1.last_name}" %>
    (<span class="total"><%= @player1.total_points %></span>)
  </h3>
</div>
```

Then you'd probably want to controller server side to increment the player's total points and send back the new total. That would leave you with something like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#player1').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.post 'whatever-the-url-is', (new_total) ->
      $('#player1 .total_points').html(new_total)
```

If you're not storing anything on the server then you could do it like this:

```
$ ->
  $('#player1').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $t = $('#player1 .total_points')
    $t.html(parseInt($t.html(), 10) + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! Quick followup question: What do I use to reference new_total in the controller action that is called by the url? I've tried params[:new_total] and it's nil. Thanks again?

Comment: That depends on how you call [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), usually you say `$.post 'some-url', data, callback` where `data` will be the object that ends up in `params` in your controller. So the `data` you use in CoffeeScript determines how you interpret `params`. Also, you wouldn't send the new total to the server, the server would just send a single column increment down to the database, pull the new total out of the database, and send that back.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'm pretty new at this and I think that went over my head. What I included above was a simplified version of my real code. My real data object is now included above. Could you please provide an example of how I would access this in the controller?

Comment: I don't see any new stuff in your question. Basically, you'd a route to `config/routes.rb`, then a controller method for that route (which would be little more than an [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-increment_counter) call), then load the total out of the database, and send it back as a response.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. An issue I'm running into is that I am not running this on the /show/ page of the object, I am running it on my home page. I am storing the object's ID in the DOM, and I have retrieved it with jQuery. How can I pass the ID into the AJAX call so that I can use it in the controller, and what do I use in the controller to access it? Thanks again for the continued help.

Comment: That depends on the route. You'd probably have a POST route for `/player/:id/add_point` or something like that, then the `id` would be right in the URL and you could `$.post "/player/#{id}/add_point"` where `id` is the local (CoffeeScript) variable that holds the player's `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have opted to use jquery (which I think may be the greatest invention of the computing age :) ), this is relatively easy.

You'll want to use the post command, which will post back to your app using AJAX.  So, in your case the coffeescript would be $('#player1').click -> $.post(route, data, success method, datatype) per [the JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

The success method can then take the return data and deal with it.  If your html changes at this point, you can return html and replace the appropriate chunk of html with JQuery.  You can also return JSON, XML, etc. as you wish.  I think in this case it sounds like returning a chunk of html may be appropriate.  You'll need an appropriate view to render to do it.

Comment: Thanks! What do I use to reference data that I pass when I'm in the controller action that is called by the url?